# Вопрос по созданию бина с конструктором

Tags: java, spring, bean

Есть два класса main и postmain.

```
public class Main {
     static int rnd=555;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

и

```
public class PostMain {
int a;

public PostMain(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
public  void print(){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

}

Я хочу передать в бин postmain переменную rnd, которая находится в классе main **через конструктор**. Как сделать это через аннотации я нашел. Вопрос - как сделать это в XML файле?
Пример моего xml файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <bean id="postMain" class="tetttsts.PostMain">
        <constructor-arg 
        </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="postMain" class="tetttsts.PostMain">
    <constructor-arg name="a" value="#{T(tetttsts.Main).rnd}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]